# Storing a Var from a function

Tags: javascript, html, json

Thanks to help on an earlier question, i am able to Retrieve a JSON and access information from it.

FINAL WORKING CODE FOR FUTURE REFERENCE

```
<script> 
    var co2;
    var url="/solarpv/api/co2/list"
    var jsonObject;

    $(document).ready(function(){
       $.getJSON(url,function(result){
          var jsonObject = result;
          alert(result[0].Cumulative_CO2);
          co2 = result[0].Cumulative_CO2;
          alert(co2);
          $('#ajaxRequest').html("An average person uses " + co2 + " pounds of c02");

       });
    }); 
</script>

<h3> Some CO2 Comparisons </h3>
<p style="width:600px;">  </p>
<ul>
    <li>An average person produces 1.98 pounds a day of CO2. </li>
    <li> Plants absorb .0040786 lbs per meter squared per day. </li>
    <li> An average tree absorbs 48.061 pounds of CO2 per year. </li>
    <li id="ajaxRequest"> 
       <script>
          document.write("An average person uses " + co2 + " pounds of c02");
       </script>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, When I store the results in a `var` called `co2` and then use that in my html like this
 it prints `undefined` for the co2 variable on my page.

both alerts `alert(result.Cumulative_CO2);` and `alert(co2);` print the same thing, so for some reason co2 is not keeping its value when it leaves the function.   any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE

This is what the URL called returns `[{"Cumulative_CO2":"406465.968076","Year":"2013","Month":"3","Day":"30"}]`

Comment: Can you show how the result JSON object looks like ?

Comment: Are you printing the HTML ***after*** the AJAX call returned successfully?

Comment: When exactly you're using `co2`? Are you displaying the variable in the HTML _before_ or while you're doing your JSON call?

Comment: The JSON call is asynchronous. Are you sure the request has completed, when you use the variable?

Comment: co2 raises into the atmosphere and creates holes..

Comment: It does not 'leave the function'. You seem to miss the point that 'below' <> 'after' in JS, when dealing with async functions. And AJAX _is_ async.

Comment: @jandy I think so too

Comment: Can you please post actual code that demonstrates the issue? With the `<p>` element directly after the script the way it is, you won't get `undefined` in place of `co2` as you claim. Seems clear that you've verified that the value is in the callback, but for some reason you're trying to use it outside the callback. This won't work on an Asynchronous AJAX call.

Comment: ...and now that you've shown the JSON result, your claim that `alert(result.Cumulative_CO2);` will give you the expected value is also not true. Why are you posting misleading information? Why not post actual code instead of making stuff up?

Comment: @squint   i didnt think I was posting misleading information,  the only thing i changed is the <p> where i try to use the co2 because I didnt think there was a difference.   when `alert(result.Cumulative_CO2)` prints it shows 406465.968076

Comment: @Mike: That's not possible. At least according to the JSON response you've shown. What you've shown is in an Array, so it would be `result[0].Cumulative_CO2`. But the main point I'm trying to get across is to post actual code that you've verified to correctly represent the issue.

Comment: @squint I'm sorry.  I see what you mean now.   `result[0].Cumulative_CO2` is what I am using.  the original code I had up there was from an earlier solution attempt, I was grabbing code from the wrong file.   The code posted now is the exact code I use

Comment: Much better! :-) You could actually accomplish this by making a "synchronous" AJAX request. In other words, one that blocks until the request is complete. This is usually not recommended though. The solutions below are better. The one with the code example will work. Just put an ID attribute on the targeted `<LI>` element, and then change the code in the answer from `$("p").html(...` to `$("#your_id").html(...`

Comment: It worked!  holy cow.   thanks for sticking with me as a blindly stumbled through this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the $.getJSON is done loading just inject your variable into the paragraph. That way once the object is stored and co2 is created jQuery will change the sentence to the proper content you want and the variable will be inserted. Here's an example.

```
<script> 
    var co2;
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $.getJSON(url,function(result){
          var jsonObject = result;
          alert(result.Cumulative_CO2);
          co2 = result.Cumulative_CO2;
          $('p').html('random co2 fact here ' + co2 + ' pounds of c02');
       });
    }); 
</script>
```

- this is untested code but it's pretty simple and should work.

Answer (score 3):

The function you pass to `ready()` won't run until after the DOM has been constructed.

`getJSON` will send an HTTP request and then finish (allowing execution to continue). The function you pass to `getJSON()` won't run until an HTTP response has been received.

You won't be able to use the response data until both those events have occurred. Until then it will be `undefined`.

Move your logic for using the data so it is inside the function you pass to `getJSON`. That is the point of having a callback function there.

Comment: I don't think I actually have to use AJAX, it was just the best solution I found searching the web.  If there is a better way to retrieve the JSON and pull out the information I need I would gladly use that.

Comment: If you want the browser to retrieve the data over HTTP, then that is Ajax. Otherwise you have to make your server do it and inject the data into the page before sending it to the browser.

Comment: ok, so it is AJAX I want then.   I dont know what you mean when you say to move my logic into the function passed to `getJSON`.   I will try to find more examples online

Comment: I got it to work and posted the code above.  Was that what you were refering to?